# Google Analytics: How can I see the referral of a referral?

Tags: google-analytics

We have two sites: site A and site B. We manage both.

Site A allows the user to prepare an order which then gets POSTed to site B via a form.

When looking at the GA statistics for site B, I want to be able to see the referral source to site A instead of seeing site A as the referral. How can this be achieved?

Is adding site A to the Referral Exclusion list of site B sufficient? Or do I need to do more than that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are two different GA properties then adding to the referral exclusion list will simply mean that the referring domain appears as direct traffic.

To get the campaign info from the referring domain you would need to set up cross-domain tracking between the two domains.

As an alternative you could store the original traffic source e.g. in a cookie and append it via campaign parameters to all links that go to your other domain. However this would be a lot of work and quite error prone.

Comment: Thanks. Do you HAVE to use the same tracking code across both domains for cross-domain tracking?

Comment: Yes. Cross domain tracking only works if you use the same GA property for both sites.